# session variable content getting lost. form comparison not happening

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method='post'>
  <label for="textbox">Scan Tracking ID  </label>
    <input  type="text"  name="blah" >
   <input type = "Submit" value="submit" name = "submit">                 
     </form>
<?php
session_start();
$s=array();

$s=$_SESSION['arr3'];
    //print_r($s);


if((isset($_POST['blah'])) && !empty($_POST['blah']) && isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST['blah']; //note i used $_POST since you have a post form **method='post'**
    echo $name;
       foreach( $_SESSION['arr3'] as $key => $obj)
                        {                       
                        if ($obj['ano'] == $name)
                        {
                            echo'<script>alert("item present")</script>'; 
                        }       
 else{
                            echo '<script> alert("item is not present");</script>';
 }}
}
else
    session_destroy();

?>
```

In the above code i have a form that is supposed to send me values from the text field. This value is caught in the $name variable and i need to compare this particular variable against the contents of the array `$_SESSION['arr3']`. When i first run the page the `$_SESSION['arr3']` has values present in it, but when i enter a value in the text field and hit submit, the comparison of this value is not happening and i am encountering an undefined index 'arr3' error.

My `$_SESSION['arr3']` is as follows,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dono] => 2015081
            [ano] => 5153350
            [ord] => 6974000
            [form] => 
            [ext] => 
            [fl] => 
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dono] => 2015081
        [ano] => 5153351
        [ord] => 7644600
        [form] => 
        [ext] => 
        [fl] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [dono] => 2015081
        [ano] => 5153352
        [ord] => 4845100
        [form] => 
        [ext] => 
        [fl] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [dono] => 2015081
        [ano] => 5153353
        [ord] => 60082200
        [form] => 
        [ext] => 
        [fl] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [dono] => 2015000
        [ano] => 5153354
        [ord] => 6417400
        [form] => 
        [ext] => 
        [fl] => 
    )

  )
```

Note: The text field in the form will be given the values present in the ano entries of the array. If there is a match then it prints the item is present. else item is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Your `session_start()` should always be the first thing on the page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$s=array();

$s=$_SESSION['arr3'];

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method='post'>
  <label for="textbox">Scan Tracking ID  </label>
    <input  type="text"  name="blah" >
   <input type = "Submit" value="submit" name = "submit">                 
     </form>
<?php
    //print_r($s);


if((isset($_POST['blah'])) && !empty($_POST['blah']) && isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST['blah']; //note i used $_POST since you have a post form **method='post'**
    echo $name;
       foreach( $_SESSION['arr3'] as $key => $obj)
                        {                       
                        if ($obj['ano'] == $name)
                        {
                            echo'<script>alert("item present")</script>'; 
                        }       
 else{
                            echo '<script> alert("item is not present");</script>';
 }}
}
else
    session_destroy();

?>
```

**Update**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['someValue'] = array("1","2");
$vExploded = implode('|', $_SESSION['someValue']);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name as $blah;
    $vExploded = $_POST['someValue'];
    $vExplodedArray = explode('|', $vExploded);
    if(in_array($name, $vExplodedArray))
    {
        echo "Name exists";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Name doesn't exist";
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="someValue" value="<?php echo $vExploded; ?>">
<input  type="text"  name="blah" >
</form>
```

Comment: 5153350
Notice: Undefined index: arr3 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\testpass.php on line 22

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\xampp\testpass.php on line 22

Thats the error I am getting.

Comment: @Sharath
You'll for surely get that.
`$s=$_SESSION['arr3'];` should be `$_SESSION['arr3'] = $s;`

Comment: made the changes but now it is just echoing $name values and not executing the comparison of $name value, whether or not if it is present in the array.

Comment: 5153350array(0) { }  Thats the output

Comment: Your array doesn't contain anything. Foreach loop won't run here. In your code, you're no where passing any value to the `$s` array.

Comment: It does. Help me rectify. Initially when the page is loaded, the session array contains the values that i have shown in the context. All i want to do is take in a form field value (ano)  and on submit check if that value is present in the session array in the respective ano key value.

Comment: @Sharath
I don't see anywhere that you pass values to the array mate. Where do you add values to your array?

Comment: okay, ignore my implementation, I am seeking help to implement it in a way wherein i use the session array throughout. How do i retain the values? I get that on var_dump it is evident that the array is not holding values. But all i want is the initial content of the session array to persist throughout all the comparisons i wish to make. Badly need help implementing this.

Comment: @Sharath
If I've understood correctly what you need, I've made a small prototype to help you out. Please read my updated answer.